# Using SQL server code to dynamically fill loop values in python

Tags: python, sql-server, loops

I’m looking to run a loop in Python where the values can vary from month to month, so the best way is to get this via SQL Server module, so something like:

```
Select distinct productid
from tablex
where date between getdate()-7 and getdate()-1
```

Would return say 300, 434, 576 one week and 948, 274, 664, 914 the next, so I'd want this to populate the list for the loop so that it would only run for certain productids depending on the week, does anyone know a way to get the aforementioned SQL code into the loop to save me manually running the code and copy and pasting into my script?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you already have a Python module for accessing your SQL Server?

Comment: Yes mssqlclient

Comment: OK, and do you already have code to query the database with that client?  Can you show us?